# Autohotkey remap key combination part of which was already remaped

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

My notebook keyboard have Insert key as Fn modifier for Delete and physical PrintScreen key. So I remap PrintScreen to Insert with Autohotkey:

`PrintScreen::Insert`

But I want to keep Winkey+PrintScreen as copy screenshot to the buffer key, so I try to do next reamp:

`#Insert::#PrintScreen`

And it doesn't work. I also tried Winkey+Control+PrintScreen and it doesn't wotk either:

`^#Insert::#PrintScreen`
`^#PrintScreen::#PrintScreen`

How do I make Winkey + PrintScreen shortcut work, if I already remapped PrintScreen to Insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
PrintScreen::Insert

; Win + PrintScreen
#PrintScreen::Send, {PrintScreen}
; Alt + PrintScreen = screenshot of the active window
!PrintScreen::Send, !{PrintScreen}
```

Comment: Now everything works fine, thank you )